# Upgrade azure event hub

Tags: azure, azure-eventhub

How to upgrade EXISTING azure event hub from standard to premium or to dedicated plan?

Is it requires deleting the existing cluster & recreating the cluster with upgraded plan or we try upgrade without deleting the cluster?

In case, if upgrading the existing cluster possible, will the data in the partition rearranges when partition count increases from 32 to 100?

I cant see option in my azure portal to upgrade event hub to other higher pricing tier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately you cannot upgrade from standard to premium according to [the docs](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/main/articles/event-hubs/includes/event-hubs-premium-faq.md#can-i-migrate-my-standard-namespaces-to-premium-namespace):

> We currently don't support migrating from standard namespaces to premium namespace.

Nor can you move to a dedicated cluster according to [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-hubs/event-hubs-faq#can-i-migrate-my-standard-or-premium-namespaces-to-a-dedicated-tier-cluster):

> We don't currently support an automated migration process for migrating your event hubs data from a standard or premium namespace to a dedicated one.

You will have to create a new event hub, reroute current message producers to this new instance, drain the current instance and then remove it.

Regarding partition changes, this is only allowed for premium and dedicated tiers and existing data won't be redistributed over the old and new partitions. One of the reasons I suppose is that the event hub cannot know whether a publisher specifically targeted a partition or not. So redistribution could mess things up. Also, all checkpoints would have te be updated too somehow.

Comment: One clarification though "One of the reasons I suppose is that the event hub cannot know whether a publisher specifically targeted a partition or not", EH knows whether publisher specifically targeted a partition or not especially publisher mentioning partition key, isn't it?

Comment: Adding dynamic partitions wont leads to ordering problem?

Comment: draining the current instance to this new instance, won't leads to duplicate processing?

Comment: *EH knows whether publisher specifically targeted a partition or not especially publisher mentioning partition key, isn't it?*, yes, but once it has been send to the specified partition there is no metadata stored that says so.

Comment: *Adding dynamic partitions wont leads to ordering problem* No, as messages are not actively rebalanced between all the partitions. But only if you read from the same partition. Order over all partitions is not supported anyhow. From the docs: *Event Hubs ensures that all events sharing a partition key value are stored together and delivered in order of arrival.*

Comment: *draining the current instance to this new instance, won't leads to duplicate processing* No, not when you start sending all new messages to the new instance and have the old processors empty the queue before being phased out.

Comment: so dynamic partitions should be consider, if you introduce partition key(s) to the system. Otherwise on existing EH with existing set of partition keys where absolute order preservation is required, introducing dynamic partitions wont make any difference as "EH ensures that all events sharing a partition key value are stored together"